# ESP32 cam offline

Tags: esp32, camera

Can the ESP32 cam be used with no internet connection.

I have my newly acquired ESP32-CAM up and running as per this really great tutorial:

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-cam-video-streaming-face-recognition-arduino-ide/

But I just realized the sketch has no HTML in it and must rely on internet access.

I need to stream video to my tablet when I don't have an internet connection.

Possible using the ESP32 Cam?

Comment: You could make your own WiFi-Network with the ESP32, just google for it. Then you'd have to connect your tablet to it and open the Website.

Comment: Why do you think, that the linked tutorial requires internet access?

Comment: When I shutdown my access to the internet (via my phone hotspot) the ESP32 CAM stops streaming.   But upon closer examination if I reboot the router as well.... even with no inter connection it works again.  Guess I have egg on my face.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just write a sketch that does what you want. The camera operation has nothing to do with the internet. Only the pretty website that is coded into that sketch.